# Is there a way to add a (tape) device to a running Solaris zone without reboot?

Tags: solaris, zones

Is it possible? IBM Tivoli seems to have [devadd](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/tsminfo/v6/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.itsm.srv.doc/t_device_driver_tsm_installing_solaris_zones_sun.html) command, so it should be possible - any knows what devadd does to achive it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the official procedures say to reboot, but just a theory, what happens if you go into the zone root from the global zone and use mknod to manually create the device node?  You definitely won't be able to do it inside the zone as one the purposes of a zone is to prevent access to resources not assigned to it.  I don't have a tape drive available on a dev system to try it out.

Comment: Surprisingly it seems to work; at least an admin who tried it reports that it does. Thanks.

Comment: Great.  I'll have to remember that one.  Just tell the admin not to forget to add it with zonecfg or it will vanish next reboot.

Comment: The admin reported that he didn't add it there with zonecfg and it didn't vanish with the next reboot... unfortunately I don't have access to the system so I cannot confirm it :(